# Book where the main character builds machine to travel to another Earth to see his parents

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book where the main who has red hair and green eyes (I think) character builds a machine to travel to another Earth to see his parents.

Here a few things that happened that I remember:

- The main character nails leather to his shoes to appear like he growing
- In another chapter the main character meets someone who helps him build the machine but the main character notices something and throws an axe at his legs which turns out to be stilts (Not sure if actually threw the axe but I definitely remember an axe)
- the machine they build at some point is invisible as there is a scene where it's raining and there is like a square where it's not raining
- The other character betrays him in the end and dies.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! When exactly did you read this? And what do you mean by your second bullet point, "_another chapter that he meets and throws an act at his legs_"?

Comment: Perhaps "another _character_ that he meets and throws an _axe_ at his legs"...?

Comment: I’ve updated it, sorry I wrote this at 11pm when I remembered the book.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this?